# Merge tags [vms] & [openvms]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I suggest merging these two tags: as of 2015-05-06 [vms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vms) has 53 questions and [openvms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvms) 86, and 19 with both. Of the remaining 34 questions tagged only [vms], it seems to me that all or almost all apply equally to OpenVMS.

One could conceivably have a tag [vax-vms] for VMS on VAX, but I think that would fit barely any questions; these days even Alpha hardware is fading away.

OpenVMS (from 1992) is described as the successor to VAX/VMS (from 1977), but it is essentially a fairly clean and complete port, so that the experience for users and high-level programmers was unchanged, unless you used an unsupported product such as, if memory serves, FMS (Forms Management System), replaced by TDMS. The term ‘Open’ in the name is also somewhat misleading, in that it is not open source; I always felt it meant little more then (VAX/)VMS with go-faster stripes.

Comment: I thought the "Open" meant "not just VAX, also Alpha"? (And "VMS" is just a family name for all of VAX/VMS, MicroVMS, and OpenVMS.) I'm not sure how important that distinction is in 2015…

Comment: As a side note, [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) says OpenVMS is "since the late 1990s". That can't be right, since I haven't touched an Alpha since 1994.

Comment: @abarnert It was mostly marketing but also having a POSIX subsystem like NT, so it could tick the GOSIP box.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment (not quite yet), so I will bunder in with an "answer". If this site distinguished "VMS" (the VMS/OpenVMS operating system) from "VMs" (Virtual Machines) - i.e. case sensitive search, it would not be so much an issue. It would have to do this also in the tags.

And I agree VMS and OPENVMS should be the same tag. OPENVMS was mostly just a marketing term by DEC. People interested and qualified to answer "VMS" questions would be the same people qualified to answer "OPENVMS" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a VMS question that I saw in passing earlier, and then ran into "wait, there are two tags for VMS". OpenVMS questions are rare enough that they don't need to be split in two. And as @MarkDiaz says, OpenVMS is probably better as more Google-friendly than VMS, which tends to find queries about VMs and the occasional lost MVS user.

Comment: If you agree, I hope you voted up the question (though to be honest I am not sure if that is the mechanism by which my proposal might become accepted).